# How to delete an element from a nested object given a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JavaScript object:

```
 var obj = $scope.items[0];  //$scope.items is a plain object
 console.log(typeof obj)     //object
```

Now after this, I do some recursion and get the path (chain of properties) to be appended to 'obj', which is encoded as a string and looks like this:

```
str = ".child.splice(" + item_index + ",1)";  //item_index is an integer
```

I want to apply this to the object. I have tried it this way:

```
var objToDelete = obj += str
console.log(typeof objToDelete)  //string
```

I am trying to delete an element in the plain object, and it works if I hard-code it this way:

```
delete $scope.items[0].child.splice(1,1);
```

What I actually want to use is:

```
delete objToDelete;   // *doesn't work*
```

However this fails, since the type of 'objToDelete' is a string.

How can I retain 'objToDelete' as an object and get this working?

Comment: *"Hey guys"*... why do you exclude the ladies among us? Enough reason to downvote imo.

Comment: Collecting a string that really is partial JavaScript code, does not seem a good idea, as you'll have to revert to `eval` then. Maybe you could share the code you have that generates this string. Probably that part of the code has to be reviewed.

Comment: @trincot What a reason to downvote! Appreciate it. Wish you had focused more on the question. Anyways, there is no problem with the string that is generated. Assume it to be ".child.splice(1,1)". I couldn't think of any other approach and also I'm dealing with complicated nested JSON.

Comment: Why do you think I did not focus enough on the question? It is the reason I asked for clarification. However, you did not share the code that generates the string, so I can't help you further. Also, I regret that you did not update your question and removed the "guys" part. We live in 2016.

Comment: I updated your question and removed that gender-limiting word for you.

Answer (score 0):

What's your end goal? Would something like this work? Just change the item_index

```
delete $scope.items[0].child.splice(item_index,1);
```

If you want to make it a little easier to use you could wrap it in a function:

```
function deleteThing(thingToDelete){
    delete $scope.items[0].child.splice(thingToDelete,1);
}
```

and then just do:

```
deleteThing(2);
```

to delete item with an index of 2.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: The problem is not with the index, its about the path to delete in json that has to be appended or maybe a better approach rather than appending, which doesn't seem so right.

Comment: The concept in this answer would work just fine with recursion, which you say your doing anyway, to traverse the object. You do not want to be using eval with a string as opens up a whole host of issues. There's other options such as Object.keys to iterate an objects properties.